# Tmux status bar flashes command from #() before displaying result

Tags: tmux, subshell

I currently use the following command to display the current git branch or mercurial bookmark for the pane's working directory.  It works correctly as far as I can tell, but just before it computes the bookmark name the status bar flashes the actual text of the command that it's about to execute (it looks something like `<cd ... && ...>`) and then that gets replaced with the name of the bookmark after a moment.  How can I avoid this flash and only see the final change?

```
set-option -g status-left\
  "#(cd #{pane_current_path} &&\
    if hg status 1>&2 2>/dev/null; then\
      echo \"($(hg book | grep \"^\\s\\*\" | cut -d' ' -f 3)) \";\
    elif git status 1>&2 2>/dev/null; then\
      echo \"($(git branch | grep \"^\\*\\s\" | cut -d' ' -f 2)) \";\
    fi;\
  )"
```

Note: I am running tmux 2.2

Comment: I'm also having this problem :( Did you find a solution?

Comment: I changed it to reference the internal file where the bookmark is stored.  I didn't end up seeing how to do this in git, but for mercurial I ended up changing the command to just `echo \"($(cat /path/to/repo/.hg/bookmarks.current 2> /dev/null)) \";\ `.  I imagine there's an analogue for this in git.